# MVC route option is persisting on reload (F5) of page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following server side code in place in my MVC controller, it's a basic post, get, redirect pattern using model binding.

The problem is that after I submit the page it does the RedirectToAction sending the route option bool parameter correctly. But when I then reload the page (F5) it's still sending the route option parameter (bool) as the previous value (true), when I would expect it to send null. It seems as if the value is being persisted somehow.

Any Ideas on how to resolve this issue? Much appreciated.

Controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DischargeHuman(bool? HumanDischarged = null)
    {
        DischargeHumanViewModel dischargeHumanVM = new DischargeHumanViewModel();
        dischargeHumanVM.HumanDischarged = HumanDischarged;
        return View(dischargeHumanVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DischargeHuman(DischargeHumanViewModel dischargeHumanVM)
    {
        string username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\")).Trim('\\');
        dischargeHumanVM.UserName = username;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dischargeHumanVM.HumanDischarged = _adminTaskLogic.DischargeHuman(dischargeHumanVM.ClientID.Value, dischargeHumanVM.HumanID, dischargeHumanVM.UserName, dischargeHumanVM.DateOfDischarge.Value);
        }


        if (dischargeHumanVM.HumanDischarged.Value)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("DischargeHuman", new { dischargeHumanVM.HumanDischarged });
        }
        else
        {
            return View(dischargeHumanVM);
        }
    }
```

.cshtml code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    if (Model.HumanDischarged.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.HumanDischarged.Value)
        {
            <span style="color:blue" id="msgSpan">Human successfully discharged.</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span style="color:red" id="msgSpan">An error occurred.</span>
        }
        Model.PatientDischarged = null;
    }
...
```

view model:

```
public class DischargePatientViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client: ")]
    public int? ClientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Patient ID: ")]
    public string PatientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date Of Discharge: ")]
    public DateTime? DateOfDischarge { get; set; }

    public bool? PatientDischarged { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectClientList
    {
        get { return new SelectList(new ClientLogic().GetClients(null, false, true), "ClientID", "ClientDisplayText"); }
    }
}
```